# Could you help me to merge values of several maps?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I'm trying to do the following modification:

```
final Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> scopes = scopeService.fetchAndCacheScopesDetails();
final Map<String, Map<String, String>> scopesResponse = scopes.entrySet().stream().collect
        (Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue()
                .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> (String) s.get(SCOPE_NM), s -> (String) s.get(SCOPE_ID))))
        );
```

But I face `"Duplicate key"` error, so I'd like to change `scopeResponses` to `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`

Could you tell me how to merge values `s -> (String) s.get(SCOPE_ID)` into a `List` or `Set` in this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a `Set` for the value of the inner `Map`, and supply a merge function:

```
final Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> scopesResponse = scopes.entrySet().stream().collect
    (Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue()
            .stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.get(SCOPE_NM),
                                               s -> {Set<String> set= new HashSet<>(); set.add(s.get(SCOPE_ID)); return set;},
                                               (s1,s2)->{s1.addAll(s2);return s1;}))));
```

Or, you can construct the inner `Map` with `groupingBy`:

```
final Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> scopesResponse2 = scopes.entrySet().stream().collect
    (Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue()
            .stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.get(SCOPE_NM),
                                               Collectors.mapping(s -> s.get(SCOPE_ID),Collectors.toSet())))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`ListMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) (multimap is like a map of lists):

```
Map<String, ListMultimap<String, String>> scopesResponse = scopes.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> toMultimap(e)));
```

where

```
static ImmutableListMultimap<String, String> toMultimap(
        Map.Entry<String, List<Map<String, String>>> entry) {
    return entry.getValue().stream().collect(ImmutableListMultimap.toImmutableListMultimap(
            s -> (String) s.get(SCOPE_NM),
            s -> (String) s.get(SCOPE_ID)
    ));
}
```

If the values in the lists turn out to be duplicated, and you don't want that, use [`SetMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html) instead.